# Nested Recyler View Help Required

Tags: android

How can i use **LinearLayoutManager** Under **GridLayoutmanager** using RecylerView i want to achieve given screens

[image][image]

Comment: Seems a valid problem hence voting up

Comment: you must use linear layout and and two colums as row ans when you click in linear layout you must open that linear layouT

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach. Recently a [ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) library was open sourced. The tutorial can be found [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview) Mainly it is using an approach, that expanded rows are just different types or rows inside one `RecyclerView`. The  benefit of this approach? Lightweight view, that uses only one `RecyclerView` and not many of such views for each cell.

The GridLayoutManager also has a method to control it's span: [setSpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanSizeLookup(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup))

Hope it will point you in the good direction.